# Qual é a diferença entre «caminhar» e «andar»?

Tags: significado, verbos, diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre *caminhar* e *andar*? Ambos verbos significam *to walk*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O verbo «andar» significa muito mais do que simplesmente «caminhar». O Priberam apresenta [19 significados](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/andar). É até um verbo copulativo que «assinala o prolongamento de um estado episódico, mas veicula implicitamente a ideia de que está em vias de se tornar habitual» (*Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, p. 1312).

«Andar» tem também significados próximos de «caminhar» e nalgumas situações são sinónimos. Mas «andar» refere-se mais ao ato de locomoção, independentemente de haver ou não um caminho que é percorrido:

> - O meu filho já **anda**.
> - Aqui acaba a estrada. Podemos **andar** [=ir a pé] o resto do caminho.
> - Nunca vi ninguém **andar** tão depressa.

«Caminhar» também pode ser usado neste sentido, mas é formal, ou pouco natural. Geralmente, «caminhar» significa percorrer um caminho (a pé); o registo é um pouco mais alto e é muitas vezes usado em sentido figurado:

> - Quando **caminhamos** da Praça do Império para a rua de Belém, no local onde divergem a rua dos Jerónimos e a Calçada do Galvão, atingimos o Largo do Chafariz de Belém [...].
> - Ele costumava **caminhar** pelo bairro. [Curiosamente, ***andar** pelo bairro* é possível, mas não significa necessariamente que ele se deslocava a pé]
> - *[figurado]* Marreiros Alves, da CDU, **caminha** para o terceiro mandato à frente do município de Aljezur.
> - *[figurado]* Estamos a **caminhar** para a destruição da arte em nome da própria arte, e da sua difusão.

«Andar» não pode ser usado em três das frases acima (e noutra não tem o mesmo significado); talvez por não ter tanto essa noção de caminho/destino, não se usa com a preposição «para» (na primeira frase, poderia usar-se «andar até», com a noção próxima de limite).

Answer (score 6):

Complementando o que já foi dito na resposta acima, em pt-BR é comum usarmos o verbo "caminhar", em preferência a "andar, quando estamos nos referindo à atividade física, ao exercício.

> - "Eu geralmente caminho pela manhã. Tenho feito caminhadas de 10 km."
> - "O médico recomendou que eu caminhasse pelo menos 20 minutos diariamente."

É menos comum ouvirmos "ando pela manhã" e "que eu andasse".

Comment: Na primeira, seria estranho usar «ando» em Portugal (pensaria «andas o quê?», ou seja, não conseguiria recuperar o significado «caminhar» de «andar»), seria «dou um passeio», «faço uma caminhada», dependendo de quão séria fosse a atividade. Na segunda, «andasse» serve perfeitamente. «Caminhar» também está bem nos dois casos, mas soa um pouco formal.

Comment: Ele quis dizer que caminhada é o nome do exercício, e o comum é usar o verbo adequado para se tratar do assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Caminhe a pe...se vc não caminhar a pe de que outro jeito vc vai caminhar????de ônibus, de carro?lógico q não...então use caminhe a pe.
Andar e só para designar com que vc vai andar e não caminhar....ex.vou andar de carro vc não é correto dizer vou caminhar de carro.

Comment: *Andar* também pode ser 'andar a pé', além de ter montes de outros significados.