# Ambos(as) os(as) + substantivo -- O porquê do artigo

Tags: origem-histórica, sintaxe

Por que a expressão *ambos(as) os(as) + substantivo* conservou o artigo definido? Ou melhor, por que não devemos dizer nem escrever *ambas pessoas formaram-se em Letras Português/Polaco*, e sim *ambas as pessoas...*?

Comment: No post https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-caminhar-e-andar o consulente escreveu "... Ambos verbos significam *to walk*." Não deveria ele ter escrito "Ambos *os* verbos..."?

Comment: Creio que já vem do latim vulgar ou tardio, porque *ambos os* ou equivalente já ocorre no português, espanhol e occitano antigos, e é assim também hoje no italiano. Digo latim vulgar ou tardio porque o latim clássico não tinha artigos definidos. Os artigos definidos das línguas românicas vêm dos pronomes demonstrativos latinos *ille*, etc. ('aquele'), e encontra-se no latim clássico *ambo illi*; era equivalente a 'ambos aqueles'; não sei se isto favoreceu o *ambos os* e equivalentes das línguas românicas.

Comment: Sim, *ambos os verbos* é a norma. Mas eu encontrei vários casos de *ambas nações* e *ambos países* em textos cuidados no sXX. Nomeadamente a partir de 1973, *ambos países* é comum no [Diário do Congresso Nacional](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CT5NAQAAIAAJ&q=%22ambos+pa%C3%ADses%22&dq=%22ambos+pa%C3%ADses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsOy9x5XXAhXSnJAKHdRTByk4ZBDoAQjJATAa) no Brasil. E antes que digam que é coisa de político, *ambas nações* aparece ainda antes noutros autores, e com alguma frequência.

Comment: Márcio, esta tua pergunta está a ser discutida no [Falatório](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo de Cunha e Cintra, "ambos" só tem a obrigação de anteceder artigo no caso em que o substantivo determinado pelo numeral estiver claro. Exemplos dados na gramática: "Eram centenares de pessoas de ambos os sexos." (só podem existir sexos masculino e feminino, por isso está determinado, mas é algo que fica realmente no subentendido) e "Vasco apoiou os cotovelos nela e segurou o rosto com ambas as mãos." Desta maneira, a sua construção vai depender do contexto. "Estevão andava ao redor delas, ambas pessoas de fino trato", mas "Ambas as pessoas que vieram aqui são culpadas." . Existem mais dois exemplos, um no jornal O Globo [link](https://oglobo.globo.com/rio/presidente-da-rufolo-ficou-em-silencio-durante-depoimento-na-pf-4414784) e num site de notícias on-line [link](https://faroldacidade.com.br/noticias/abrir/Covid-19-faz-mais-duas-vitimas-em-Guanambi;-ambas-pessoas-bastante-conhecidasabrir/2545/). É interessante notar que o uso  do ambas SEM o artigo é utilizado na última porque está na chamada, não se sabe quem são as pessoas, mas na matéria seria utilizado com artigo porque ele diz quem são as pessoas acometidas pela doença.

Answer (score -2):

Quando dizemos "ambos os/as" estamos dizendo "tanto um quanto o outro" indivíduo. Por isso devemos preservar o artigo.

In English, we usually say "both of them are cool, funny" or something like that right? In Portuguese, the article has a similar function that the preposition "of" has in English.
 I hope to have helped!

Comment: Who cares about the English? There is no article in ambas, ambos.

Answer (score -2):

porque AMBOS já está se referindo a duas ou mais pessoas ou coisas sem precisar cita-las na frase.